# Datalist paging in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net Web application, i write code for datalist paging like this :

```
PagDat = new PagedDataSource();
PagDat.AllowPaging = true;
PagDat.PageSize = 10;
PagDat.CurrentPageIndex = **currentpage**;
PagDat.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dtlstMagazine.DataSource = PagDat;
dtlstMagazine.DataBind();
```

In this "currentpage" is a integer varaible which i declared as a static. I think it  could be conflict when more user access this page am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes your are right.**

> You should Save your PageDataSouce `page index in State Management
>   object`. using static variable is not a good approach in web
>   application for such page level operations.

Create CurrentPage `property`:

```
public int CurrentPage
{
   get
   {
      // look for current page in ViewState
      object o = this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"];
      if (o == null)
         return 0; // default page index of 0
      else
         return (int) o;
   }

   set
   {
      this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value;
   }
}
```

Check following link for more information:
[Adding Paging Support to the Repeater or DataList with the PagedDataSource Class](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx)